# Sending email with html in Django 1.7

Tags: python, html, django, email

In **send_mail()** we have one new parameter - `html_message`. [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#send-mail)

I have **email.html** file and I want to send html version of my message. I can't find any example for Django 1.7.

Can you show me a way, how to do this? Does I need to use **os.open()** my html file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`render_to_string` : which loads a template, renders it and returns the resulting `string`.
`html_message` : If `html_message` is provided, the default message replaced with Html message.

**mail/html-message.html**

```
Hi {{ first_name }}.

    This is your {{ email }}

Thank you
```

**views.py**

```
def mail_function(request):
    subject = 'Test Mail'
    from = 'info@domain.com'
    to = 'to@domain.com'
    c = Context({'email': email,
                 'first_name': first_name})
    html_content = render_to_string('mail/html-message.html', c)
    txtmes = render_to_string('mail/text-message.html', c)
    send_mail(subject,
              txtmes,
              from,
              [to],
              fail_silently=False,
              html_message=html_content)
```

Comment: Context is deprecated in django 1.10+ please use normal dictionary instead of context

Answer (score 0):

Tim,

You don't need OS.open. You can do this by creating an html template first, and importing it using the get_template method. In your 
view, add something along the lines of :

**app/view.py**

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives    
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import get_template

def send_mail(request):
    text = get_template('email_template.txt')
    html = get_template('email_template.html')
    data = {'templating variable': data_var}
    # If Client cant receive html mails, it will receive the text
    # only version. 

    # Render the template with the data
    content_txt = text.render(data)
    content_html = html.render(data)

    # Send mail
    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, content_text, from_email, [to])
    msg.attach_alternative(content_html, "text/html")
    msg.send()
```

**Note**: You don't need Context for Djange 1.10+. In Django 1.8+, the template's render method takes a dictionary for the context parameter. Support for passing a Context instance is deprecated, and gives an error in Django 1.10+.

Comment: I need my template to have dynamic fields where i can specify who to sent this mail. Can you update the answer with html part of approach also.