# Django 1.7: how to send emails by using an html/css file as template

Tags: python, html, css, django, email

From Django 1.7, it is possible to `send_email()` with a new parameter: `html_message`. Unfortunately, there is not a comprehensive guide (newby friendly) on how to use it (or at least I could not find it).

I need to make sent emails nice and, thus, I'm trying to figure out how to include my message into a html/css template.
I've read many posts about this subject, but most of them refer to previous version of Django. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27122584/sending-email-with-html-in-django-1-7) post is for Django 1.7 but the answer shows the usage of a very basic html file.

**my_html_message.html**

```
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <link href="path/to/application.css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="email_header">
    [..]
    <a href="http://mysite.it"><img src="images/logo.png"/></a>
  </div>
  <div class="email_body">
   [..]
   {{my_message}}
  </div>
 </body>
```

**my_message.txt**

```
 Dear {{username}}, 
 you won {{money}}.
```

**my_function.py**

```
def my_send_email(request):
 subject = 'Test html email'
 from = 'my@email.com'
 to = 'yours@email.com'
 my_context = Context({'username': user.username,
             'money': user.money})
 html_message = render_to_string('mail/my_html_message.html', c)
 message = render_to_string('mail/my_message.txt', c)
 send_mail(subject,
          message,
          from,
          [to],
          html_message=html_message)
```

How can I pass to `my_html_message.html` the file `my_message.txt` with `my_context` and send an email with a custom style?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With **[include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#include)**:

```
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <link href="path/to/application.css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="email_header">
    [..]
    <a href="http://mysite.it"><img src="images/logo.png"/></a>
  </div>
  <div class="email_body">
   [..]
   {% include "my_message.txt" %}
  </div>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write a HTML template for emails, you should consider write your style inline:

```
<div style="display: none;"></div>
```

Because some email clients won't display your styles as you expect. BTW, let's suppose you have a template styled in the convenient way.

```
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <link href="path/to/application.css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="email_header">
    [..]
    <a href="http://mysite.it"><img src="images/logo.png"/></a>
  </div>
  <div class="email_body">
   [..]
   Dear {{ name }}
   You won {{ money }}

   {# Or you could use include #}
  </div>
 </body>
```

I will assume that you've configured a directory for your templates, and it's working well. To send an HTML template with a context you could do this:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.template import Context

class Email():

    @staticmethod
    def send_html_email(*args, **kwargs):
        from_email = kwargs.get('from_email', 'default@email.from')
        context = Context(kwargs.get('context'))
        template = get_template(kwargs.get('template_name'))
        body = template.render(context)
        subject = kwargs.get('subject', 'Default subject here')
        headers = kwargs.get('headers', {})

        message = EmailMultiAlternatives(
                subject,
                from_email,
                kwargs.get('to'),
                headers=headers
            )

        message.attach_alternative(body, 'text/html')
        message.send(fail_silently=False)
```

Then, when you want to send an email you use the `send_html_email` method:

```
# views.py
...
data = {
          'from_email': 'my_email@whatever.com',
          'subject': 'My pretty subject',
          'to': ['recipient@email.com', ],
          'template_name': 'templates_dir/my_html_message.html',
          'context': {'name': 'Name of user', 'money': 1000},
        }

Email.send_html_email(**data)
...
```

Comment: thank you @Gocht but actually your answer is for older (then 1.7) Django version

Comment: @user123892 I use this code in a Django 1.8 project, Whant changed is that now you can define `reply-to` header as a parameter.

Comment: sorry @Gocht I did not mean your solution does not work, but that I wanted to use the new parameter html_message provided in send_mail() from Django 1.7 (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/email/#send-mail)