# djagno send html email with static file attachment such as css and js and images

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, html-email

I'm setting up a website for my self that send email with attachment.
I used this link [How to send html email with django with dynamic content in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005080/how-to-send-html-email-with-django-with-dynamic-content-in-it)  but when I send email according to this link, static files like my images and my css and js files didn't send with my email.

here my code :

```
subject, from_email, to = "WebSite Newsletter Subscribe", settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, [instance.email]
        html_content = render_to_string('newsletter/Email.html')
        text_content = strip_tags(html_content)
        msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
        msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
        msg.send()`
```

but in this code email send with bare html and not css and js doesn't include and my images doesn't attached too.
I already read this link [Django 1.7: how to send emails by using an html/css file as template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33787073/django-1-7-how-to-send-emails-by-using-an-html-css-file-as-template) but according to this link, I should convert my external css and js to internal and there isn't solution for my images too.
I wondet How can I solve my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django 1.7: how to send emails by using an html/css file as template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33787073/django-1-7-how-to-send-emails-by-using-an-html-css-file-as-template)

Comment: @mikirinRoman I read this link and it isn't help me

Comment: I've never had such problems, do you use absolute paths for all resources?

Comment: @mikirinRoman yes